# Insert span after button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to insert a span tag after all button elements.

Here's what I have:

```
    <button>button text 1</button>
    <button>button text 2</button>
    <button>button text 3</button>
```

Here's what I want:

```
    <button><span>button text 1</span><button>
    <button><span>button text 2</span><button>
    <button><span>button text 3</span><button>
```

I've tried using

```
    var content = $('button').html();
    $('button').empty().html('<span>' + content + '</span>');
```

But if I had more than one button on the div it would replicate the first value to the remaining buttons

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the jQuery `wrapInner()` method like such:

```
$('button').wrapInner('<span></span>')
```

http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").wrapInner("<span></span>");
});
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/42gvqu3q/1/
(inspect elements to see the result)

> Description: Wrap an HTML structure around the content of each element
>   in the set of matched elements.

http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('button').each(function(){
    var content = $(this).html();
    $(this).empty().html('<span>' + content + '</span>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Hello!</button>
<button>Hello!</button>
<button>Hello!</button>
```

Use `$.each jQuery` function:

```
$('button').each(function(){
    var content = $(this).html();
    $(this).empty().html('<span>' + content + '</span>');
});
```

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Answer (score 2):

use wrapInner(), and a each loop

```js
    var $buttons = $('button');
     $buttons.each(function(){
      $(this).wrapInner( "<span class='new'></span>");
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>button text 1</button>
    <button>button text 2</button>
    <button>button text 3</button>
```

Comment: Is there any reason to use the `each` loop when `$('button').wrapInner()` will apply it to all of them anyway?

Comment: you're right, I upvote your answer. However using loop can let you
more flexibility to set ids or whatever you want

Comment: agreed, I was just wondering why for this example, thanks for the vote

Answer (score 0):

Should select each button and replace the innerHTML as below:

```js
 var $buttons = $('button');
 var content = "";
 $buttons.each(function(){
   content = $(this).html();
   $(this).html('<span>' + content + '</span>');
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop and use this.

```js
var content = '';
$('button').each(function(index, element) {
  content = $(this).html();
  $(this).empty().html('<span>' + content + '</span>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>button text 1</button>
<button>button text 2</button>
<button>button text 3</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You either use wrapInner, or if you would like to use your code, you have to use each.

```
<div class"each">
  <button>button text 1</button>
  <button>button text 2</button>
  <button>button text 3</button
</div>
<div class="wrap">
  <button>button text 1</button>
  <button>button text 2</button>
  <button>button text 3</button
</div>

$('.each button').each(function(button) {
  var content = $(this).html();
  $(this).empty().html('<span>' + content + '</span>');
})

$('.wrap button').wrapInner('<span></span>')
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n300cn52/